# We have an Opp with two Primary Contacts - out of curiosity how is that possible?

Tags: opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

[image]

So though the GUI it would appear you can only have one primary contact on an opp.  However we have just found an Opp with two primary contacts.  Which is breaking a script we have.

I cant think how this is possible as can not happen though the GUI.  Guessing it may be due to records being merged or something.

NB the list of roles contained a couple of dupe contacts.

Just curious - any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one primary contact... But they have multiple roles. Salesforce allows this, so you must account for this. Keep in mind that any role record with primary on an opportunity will have the same contact as all primary roles for the opportunity.

While the UI implies that only one record can be made primary, you can cause this to happen by selecting the same contact twice on the role edit screen, then select either as the primary role. Once saved, they'll both be checked as primary.